# Lumen route groups error: "Undefined variable: app"

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I just created a new **lumen** application with this very simple routes file:

```
<?php

$app->get('/', function () {
  return 'Hello World';
});


$app->group(['prefix' => '/admin'], function () {

  $app->get('/user', function () {
    return 'Admin user';
  });

});
```

And I get this error:

```
lumen.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined variable: app' in /path/to/my/lumen/project/app/Http/routes.php:10
```

What's wrong?

Note that if I remove the route group everything works great.

Comment: Can you post the whole file so we know which line it's actually on about and why the error would be showing?

Comment: @gabe3886 Done. The error is in the $app inside the group. This line: `$app->get('/user', function () {`

Comment: @Andrea: `$app` is out of scope for the callback/closure, pass a reference to `$app` using the `use` keyword (cf my answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the closure you're using in the `group` call:

```
$app->group(['prefix' => '/admin'], function () {

        $app->get('/user', function () {
        return 'Admin - user';
    });

});
```

You'll have to pass it a reference to `$app`:

```
$app->group(['prefix' => '/admin'], function () use ($app) {

        $app->get('/user', function () {
        return 'Admin - user';
    });

});
```

The lumen docs on the laravel website contained an error, but the docs on [github](https://github.com/laravel/lumen-docs/blob/5.0/routing.md#route-groups) have been fixed. As it turns out, the application instance is passed as an argument to the callback, so you can do away with that `use ($app)` bit, and instead write this:

```
$app->group(['prefix' => '/admin'], function ($app) {

        $app->get('/user', function () {
        return 'Admin - user';
    });
});
```

Comment: Yeah. Nailed it! Now it works. But someone should update the Lumen's documentation here http://lumen.laravel.com/docs/routing#route-groups

Comment: @Andrea: The docs [on github](https://github.com/laravel/lumen-docs/blob/5.0/routing.md#route-groups) have been fixed already, `$app` seems to be passed as an argument to the callback. I'll add that to my answer